# change MAC address in USB device

Tags: network

I'm trying to change the MAC on a USB wifi device. The usual way of doing it does nothing...

```
sudo ifconfig en4 ether 11:22:33:44:55:66
```

After doing the command there are no errors, but the MAC stays the same. I've tried disconnecting the device from any network before trying to change it... and nothing changes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you're using the generic Apple-supplied driver for the USB WiFi device, or if you're using a vendor-supplied driver that doesn't support changing the MAC address.

You'll need to install the vendor-supplied driver for your adapter, if you haven't already. If you cannot find a driver for your specific product, you might be able to find a driver for a different product using the same WiFi chipset - that might work.

When you have the vendor-supplied driver installed, the command you have supplied could then be able to change the MAC address.